# Как в js поменять id элемента по условию

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день.

В *HTML* документе документе есть набор мини картинок

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="miniVert" src="images/do_prof.jpg" onclick="setBigImage(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;"></a>
```

По нажатию на каждую, она выводится в большем размере в элементе:

```
<div id="resimagewrapper">              
    <img id="bigCertVert" src="images/teach_ut.jpg" oncontextmenu="return false;" />
</div>
```

С помощью функции:

```
function setBigImage(obj){
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').src = obj.src;               
}
```

Все картинки были альбомной ориентации, поэтому размеры элемента `#bigCertVert` были жестко заданы.
Сейчас появились картинки книжной ориентации, создал элемент вывода в данной ориентации, требуется, чтобы функция подстановки проверяла класс мини-картинки и в соответствии с ним выводила большой размер в нужном элементе.
**Нужно решение на чистом js**.  Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Т.е. у мини картинок альбомного и книжного варианта разные классы и нужно, что бы по кликну на мини картинку оно проверяло класс и изменяло размер большой картинки?

Comment: странно звучит "поменять **id** элемента по условию" хотя тут надо поменять `className`

Comment: Да, точно так. Чтобы в большом варианте тоже выводилась книжная или альбомная ориентация в зависимости от ориентации мини картинок. Пришло в голову только проверять класс мини и подставлять нужный класс биг. Но может есть и лучше варианты?

Comment: @Tariel, а можно Jquery? Или только JavaScript чистый надо?

Comment: Нужен чистый js

Comment: 2 Subkihim  Можно и класс, мне главное понять, как выводить в нужный элемент в зависимости от класса элемента по которому кликнули

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function setBigImage(obj){
  document.getElementById('bigCertVert').src = obj.src;
  if(obj.classList.contains('type0')){
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').classList.add("type0");
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').classList.remove("type1");
  }else if(obj.classList.contains('type1')){
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').classList.add("type1");
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').classList.remove("type0");
  };
}
```

```css
#resimagewrapper img.type0 {width:100px;height:50px}
#resimagewrapper img.type1 {width:50px;height:50px}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="miniVert type0" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0089b585f2499f09a32d95c06d545ba0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" onclick="setBigImage(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;"></a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="miniVert type1" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0089b585f2499f09a32d95c06d545ba0?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" onclick="setBigImage(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;"></a>
</div>
<div id="resimagewrapper">              
    <img id="bigCertVert" class="type0" src="images/teach_ut.jpg" oncontextmenu="return false;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Всем спасибо. Помогли все ответы, разобрался.  Не получается пометить ответ как полезный, не хватает репутации

Answer (score 1):

```js
function setBigImage(obj){
 if (obj.className == "miniVert"){
 document.getElementById('bigCertVert').src = obj.src; 
 } else {
 document.getElementById('bigCertHoriz').src = obj.src; 
 }                  
}
```

```css
.miniVert, .miniHoriz{
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="miniVert" src="http://images6.fanpop.com/image/photos/33400000/NEKO-k-33431290-714-714.png" onclick="setBigImage(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;"></a>

<a href="javascript:void(0);"><img class="miniHoriz" src="http://images.boomsbeat.com/data/images/full/24384/cat_4-jpg.jpg" onclick="setBigImage(this);" oncontextmenu="return false;"></a>
<div id="resimagewrapper">              
    <img id="bigCertVert" src="images/teach_ut.jpg" oncontextmenu="return false;" />
    <img id="bigCertHoriz" src="images/teach_ut.jpg" oncontextmenu="return false;" />
</div>
```

Например вот так.

Answer (score 1):

```
function setBigImage(obj){
  if (obj.classList.contains("miniVert"))
    document.getElementById('bigCertVert').src = obj.src;               
  else
    document.getElementById('bigCertHoriz').src = obj.src;               
}
```